# Trouble converting String to Java Date object

Tags: java

When I run the following code

```
package test;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateParsingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateAsString = "2016-May-30";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            Date dateAsDate = format.parse(dateAsString);
            System.out.println("dateAsDate = " + dateAsDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is: dateAsDate = Sun Dec 27 00:00:00 CST 2015

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I'll be damned if I can figure out what. Anybody know what's causing the issue?

Comment: Change `YYYY` to `yyyy`.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Next time read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: You might also try `format.format(new Date());` - which might have helped you spot the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per shmosel's comment I changed

`DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);`

to

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

according to the specifications located here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html